# Cutting Time/Date data at various intervals

Tags: r, intervals

I'm using R to analyze 365 days of data collected on over 40,000 events. The events occur at various times of the day. I wish to aggregate the events and calculate means at various intervals such as 2, 8, 12 hour or daily. I've seen CUT and AGGREGATE used but it does not appear to provide the intervals as required.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `CUT` function one must first define the break points.  In order to do that, use the `seq` function.

```
mydateseq<-seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01"), by="2 hour", length.out = 20)
```

There are options to set the start/stop points or the number of elements.  In this example the breaks are set every 2 hours but this is adjustable.  See ?seq.POSIXt for more help.  Be sure to set the start/stop to completely capture the date range of interest.
Once the date sequence is defined this can be passed to cut function to aggregate or use the group_by function in the dplyr package.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that worked great. It took me a moment to catch how it all comes together but it did work. I tested it on 12 hour groupings and now I can tweek to the 2 hour sets. Thanks... `code`  )

### group based on 12 hour sets
mydateseq<-seq(as.POSIXct("2014-12-31"), by="12 hour", length.out = 750)
raddata1$group <- cut(raddata1$a,mydateseq,right=FALSE)